# Close div, jump back to top

Tags: javascript

I have a JS script that shows and hides a div when clicked. What I am trying to do is when the close link at the bottom is clicked it jumps back up to the open link. Can't figure it out and everything I searched wants to remove this from happening.

Open link:

```
Click <a href="javascript:ShowContent('require')">Here</a>
```

Close link:

```
Click <a href="javascript:HideContent('require')">Here</a> to Close.
```

JS code I am using:

```
function HideContent(d) {
    document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none";
}

function ShowContent(d) {
    document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block";
}
```

I am sure it's something easy to fix but as per previous questions any attempts to understand JS have ended in bitter resentment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the link's default functionality.

```html
Click <a id="openLink" href="javascript:ShowContent('require')">Here</a>

Click <a href="#openLink" onclick="HideContent('require')">Here</a> to Close.
```

Comment: Like I said, something simple. Thanks!